How to interpret the results of a classifier when train/test method gives much better results than cross validated one?
I need your help to understand a situation where using train and test set produces perfect results (in terms of accuracy, precision, and recall) but when cross validation is used, the accuracy on several folds is poor.
Here is the result of a KNN classifier, when it was used on 20% test and 80% train data:
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       1.00      1.00      1.00        13
       1       1.00      1.00      1.00         7
       2       1.00      1.00      1.00        10

accuracy                               1.00        30
macro avg          1.00      1.00      1.00        30
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00        30

But when I use cross validation, using cross_val_score with the same classifier and accuracy score as scoring metric, I get the following results:
cv: 3 --- score for each fold: [0.68    1.   0.68]
cv: 4 --- score for each fold: [0.65789474    1.     1.      0.67567568]
cv: 5 --- score for each fold: [0.66666667    1.     1.    1.      0.7]

I need your suggestions and guidance about this discrepancy in terms of:

What does these varying scores represent, particularly the low scores of cross validation?
How to interpret this situation?
How to get better score at cross validation?

Thanks.
P.S: Using stratified cross validation with shuffle = True brought me [1.   1.   1.   1.   1.] results, that reflect the results I got from train/test (train/val) split.


 What does these varying scores represent, particularly the low scores of cross validation?

Together, they represent the fact that error estimtes based on a small number of tested cases are highly variable. That applies in both directions. You may be lucky in that the test set accidentally happens to be an easy subset. CV-folds may show bad performance because they unluckily happen to be a difficult subset.
Precision and recall are estimated as proportions of tested cases, and F1 is a figure of merit derived from such proportions.
Proportions suffer from high variance (compared to e.g. Brier's score; you may also want to read up about proper scoring rules).
So, if 20 % of your data are 30 cases, n = 150. The CV folds have sizes of 24 to 40 cases each.
Look at Bernoulli trials to get some idea of the variability you have to expect due to sample size alone. With that you can also calculate confidence intervals for the proportions based on the observed fraction and sample size in the test/fold
Also, CV has a (slight*) pessimistic bias compared to testing with an independent test set. (The test set in turn has worse variance, and as set up is likely not any more reliable than the cross validation estimates.)
* compared to the variance uncertainty

How to interpret this situation?

Looking at your numbers without calculating, the CV variability may be even higher than expected from the number of tested cases alone. That may be a symptom of instability in the model training causing additional variance due to model instability.
You can directly check this by repeated cross validation, see e.g. our paper:
Beleites, C. & Salzer, R. Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations, Anal Bioanal Chem, 2008, 390, 1261-1271.
I may say that we still hadn't realized that we're subject to multiple quite different sources of variance, so please disregard the paragraphs that try to estimate effective sample size.

 How to get better score at cross validation?

I don't think that is a good question in this situation. It may well be that the variability of the cross validation results give you a more realistic impression of the actual unrelability of your model.
